# Are these two connectors that look very different, both mSATA?

Tags: sata

Are these two connectors that look very different, both mSATA?

[image]

The advert on amazon says mSATA for the  smaller one in the picture.

But I wonder then if the 2.5" laptop drive is an mSATA. 'cos it the 2.5" laptop drive's SATA the same size as that on a 3.5" drive?

Also, if I type in micro SATA into google images , one of the things that shows is this

[image]

which looks rather like the smaller thing in the first pic .

But according to Wikipedia the m in mSATA stands for Mini-SATA (mSATA).

So I have no idea is the little drive in the pic micro SATA or mini SATA.  Is the 2.5" drive micro SATA or Mini SATA..  which mSATA is?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon listings (and other advertising material) are often written by sales-people with little technical know-how. Never blindly trust technical specs in those listings. Always check with the actual manufacturer of the hardware what it really is.

The 2.5 drive just is a regular SATA 2.5" SSD.

The small PCB like thing is a M.2 connector device, which can be mSATA, NVMe or both combined.
The little gap between the 2 sides of the connector is there to prevent you putting a M.2 mSATA device into a M.2 NVMe only slot. NVMe only M.2 slots have the gap in a different place.
Some M.2 devices have 2 gaps so they fit in either type of slot (and some M.2 slots only take 2-gap devices), but that doesn't always mean either the device or the slot supports BOTH mSATA and NVMe. Always check the documentation.

(NVMe is a lot faster than mSATA. So if your laptop has a M.2 slot that supports NVMe, get a NVMe SSD, not a mSATA one.)

Comment: You write "The 2.5 drive just is a regular SATA 2.5" SSD." <-- Is that different dimension or type of connector to SATA 3.5" SSD?

Comment: You write "Amazon listings (and other advertising material) are often written by sales-people with little technical know-how. Never blindly trust technical specs in those listings." <--- I haven't blindly trusted anything. I have simply looked at it as evidence and asked.. And you haven't said whether the amazon listing title was correct or not

Comment: You write "M.2 connector device, which can be mSATA" <-- This contradicts wikipedia that says "M.2 replaces the mSATA standard"

Comment: @user1686 thanks.. it'd be good if you can post an answer 'cos this guy has some important details wrong.. You write "an mSATA form factor ".   So are mSATA and M2 different form factors?  And if those are form factors, where does NVMe come into it?

Comment: Don't confuse SATA with mSATA – the latter is a _form factor_ like M.2, not a protocol. (Meaning, there is no such thing as "M.2 mSATA"; you were thinking of "M.2 SATA" SSDs.) The thing in the photo is an mSATA form factor SSD – much wider than M.2 and has two corner screws vs one.

Comment: @barlop: NVMe is a communications protocol. While mSATA slots only speak SATA (I believe), the newer M.2 slots can understand either SATA or NVMe (PCIe), so you can have M.2-shaped NVMe-speaking SSDs, M.2-shaped SATA-speaking SSDs, and mSATA-shaped SATA-speaking SSDs.

Comment: @user1686  I see, so SATA and NVMe are alternatives.  Also, when you say PCIe, do you mean mPCIe(Mini PCIe)?  Also when you say "NVMe (PCIe)"  NVMe is a communications protocol, whereas mPCIe is a form factor.

Comment: @barlop: And finally for 2.5" vs 3.5" disks, SATA describes both the protocol _and_ the connectors, and yes both sizes use completely identical "full size" SATA connectors.

Comment: @user1686 re the 2.5" vs 3.5" having the same connectors, is that for both Power and Data?

Comment: @barlop No, when I say PCIe I mean the PCI Express protocol, not any particular form factor. "M.2 NVMe" slots are tiny PCIe slots, indeed kinda like mPCIe but of course shaped differently. "M.2 NVMe" SSDs are M.2 form factor devices which connect to the PCIe bus and speak NVMe over it. Yes, there's never too many standards. At least your laptop doesn't have a soldered-in SSD.

Comment: @user1686 so if PCIe is a communication protocol and NVMe is a communication protocol.. then how can a device connect to a PCIe bus and communicate with the  NVMe communication protocol?

Comment: @barlop: Yes, both the main SATA connector (data) and the SATA Power connector are identical for both 2.5" and 3.5" disks. Though 2.5" disks don't use 12V power so laptops might not have that wired up, since you can't put a 3.5" disk into a laptop anyway.

Comment: @barlop: Protocols can work on layers – NVMe is carried on top of PCIe. It's kind of like how IP goes on top of Ethernet. Sorry, calling PCIe a communications protocol was probably the wrong choice – I meant that I was referring to the bus and not to the specific "mPCIe" form factor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118717/discussion-between-barlop-and-user1686).